# To show the given statement related to characteristic of a commutative ring.

Tags: ring-theory

Let R be a commutative ring whose characteristic is a prime p. Then show that $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ for all $a,b\in R$.

I know if P is a characteristic of ring R then P is the smallest positive integer such that $pa=0$ for all a $\in  R$.

I guess I cannot use mathematical induction here. 
How can I prove this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to prove this:

$$ (a + b)^p = \sum_{k = 0}^{p} \binom{p}{k} a^k b^{p - k} $$

What does this expand to and how does $p$ play into this?

> $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, so for $k \not= 0, p$, $p$ must be a factor of $\binom{p}{k}$. Since $\forall a. p * a = 0$ in a ring with characteristic $p$ we get that $(a + b)^p = a^p + b^p$.